# How to move the left-hand column further to the left?

Tags: beamer, spacing, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I'm using beamer to create slide. I have two columns in one slide: the left one contains a figure, and some items on the right to point out something important about the figure.

I used the following code:

```
\begin{frame}{Fig. 1}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{Figures/Fig.1.png}
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}\par%
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

My current state is that I want to move the Fig. left-er but I don't want to touch the items on the right, please help...

[image]

I got so many warnings, here are some of them:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could it be possible that your image in the left column is wider than the column itself? (Do you get an overfull box warning?) To overcome this, you could either reduce the size of the image (for example using `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]`)  or increase the width of the left column while at the same time reducing the right column's width. Replacing `\par` with `\hfill` should also help additionally.

Comment: Please extend your code snipped to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. Using it in plain `beamer` document and example image works fine. Apparently your image at given height is noticeably wider than column where it is inserted. Consider @leandriis comment.

Comment: @leandriis: Sir I think you're right, I got that warning LoL let me update my post!

Answer (score 5):

If you insert the instruction `\hfill` between the first and second `column` environment, they'll actually get pushed slightly into the left-hand and right-hand margins, respectively.

Here's another visual "trick" worth remembering: If you make the items in the `itemize` environment in the right-hand column cluster together tightly, their relative distance to the image in the left-hand column will *appear* to be larger.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem,ragged2e,caption}

%% create a bespoke itemize-like environment
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\textbullet, % choose a suitable symbol
                      nosep, left=0pt,
                      before=\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\RaggedRight,
                      after=\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame with a \texttt{columns} environment}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Fig.1.png}
        
        \captionof{figure}{Bla bla}
    \end{column}
    \hfill % <-- new
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
       \begin{myitemize}
          \item \lipsum[1][1-2]
          \item \lipsum[2][1-2]
       \end{myitemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to overlap the left margin, but `\makebox` is easiest.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Fig. 1}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \makebox[\columnwidth][r]{\includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight]{example-image}}% Figures/Fig.1.png
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}\par%
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain the parameter `[r]` following the `\makebox` command?

Comment: The options are l=left, r=right, and c=center (default), same as tabular except it works even if the contents are too wide.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to limit image width to column width:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}  % remove 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Fig. 1}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=0.55\textheight,
                                 width=\linewidth,         % <---
                                 keepaspectratio]{Figures/Fig.1.png} 
            \end{figure}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I adopted your answer :) because it is the only one understandable by me about the reason behind...

Comment: @Niing, then please accept it (by clicking check mark at top left side of answer) that site user can see, that your problem is solved.  As I see so far you not accept any answer to any of your questions.